# create survival curve with a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, survival

the survfit() function will not accept a list, so I need a way to unlist the result of Surv() without removing information from the column. For example, using the lung data:

```
library(survival)

attach(lung)

lung$survObj <- with(lung, Surv(time, status ==2))
lung.2 <- lung
mylist <- list(lung,lung.2)
```

Here is an attempt to use `lung` from my list and pass `lung$survObj` into `survfit() and group by column 5 (sex):

```
survfit(formula = mylist[[1]][11] ~ mylist[[1]][5], data = mylist[[1]])

invalid type (list) for variable 'mylist[[1]][11]'
```

but given the following:

```
nrow(mylist[[1]][11])

228
```

and

```
length(unlist[[1]][11])

456
```

i.e. double!

I get the obvious complaint that I am comparing columns of unequal length.

also notice that the `+` symbols are removed after unlisting which is vital to survfit().

Has anyone managed to call survfit on a list of dataframes?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three possible solutions to your problem.

A)

```
survfit(survObj ~ sex, data=mylist[[1]])
```

B)

```
 Y1 <- mylist[[1]]$survObj
 x1 <- mylist[[1]]$sex
 survfit(Y1 ~ x1)
```

C)

```
Y2 <- mylist[[1]][11][[1]]
x2 <- mylist[[1]][5][[1]]
survfit(Y2 ~ x2)
```

Comment: thanks Marco all work and went with the first option for automation pruposes.